# Get user positions from LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

I am trying to get the user positions and picture url when he logs in. I have permission of r_basicprofile enabled on my app and included on the scopes.

Using the url:
`https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:<userID>)?oauth2_access_token=<AccesToken>&projection=(id,firstName,lastName,positions,picture-url)`

I get the first name, last name, and ID, but nothing else. What is missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `r_fullprofile` permission according to the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/references/v2/profile/full-profile?context=linkedin%2Fconsumer%2Fcontext